# Python Libraries install but cannot be imported

Tags: python, pip

I've been trying to make a simple chatbot with voice recognition in python 3.7. I try to install the libraries using pip install into the C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages.

This seems to be where python is pulling the packages from. Previously, I have installed some packages this way and they have worked fine. But recently, none of the packages installed with pip are able to be imported.

Im on a Windows 10 Laptop

Thanks

pip freeze output:

```
altgraph==0.16.1
asgiref==3.2.10
asn1crypto==0.24.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
comtypes==1.1.7
cryptography==2.7
Django==3.0.8 
fabric==2.4.0
future==0.17.1
geojson==2.5.0
idna==2.10
invoke==1.2.0
macholib==1.11
pafy==0.5.5
paramiko==2.6.0
pefile==2018.8.8
pycparser==2.19
PyInstaller==3.4
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyowm==3.0.0
pypiwin32==223
PySocks==1.7.1
python-vlc==3.0.10114
pyttsx==1.1
pyttsx3==2.90
pytz==2020.1
pywin32==228
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
requests==2.24.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
South==1.0.2
SpeechRecognition==3.8.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
Voice==0.1.0
wikipedia==1.4.0
youtube-dl==2020.6.16.1
```

Comment: What's the output from `pip freeze`?

Comment: Pip freeze is in edit ^^^^^

Comment: Sorry, also forgot to ask what library installed successfully but could not be imported.

Comment: Im trying to install multiple ones including PyAudio, Wikipedia, bs4, requests, urllib2 and youtube_dl

Comment: make sure your pip interpreter is pointed to the right python version, try something like `python3.6 -m pip install`

Comment: Àlso, things like wikipedia, youtube_dl and urllib3 say there installed but cant be imported. SpeechRecognition requires PyAudio but I need to install Visual C++ 14.0

Comment: I was supposed to put python 3.7 sorry and pip is the same (3.7)

Comment: sometimes pip for python 3 is named pip3

Comment: Do you have multiple Python installations?

Comment: I do, 2.7 and 3.7